# Как удалить строку из базы данных используя Remove в WPF

Tags: wpf, база-данных

Пытаюсь выполнить удаление пользователя из базы данных но не понимаю какое значение надо передать Remove.

Присутствует статическое соединение с бд

`class Connect { public static AS202117Entities1 db = new AS202117Entities1(); }`

Выгружаю данные в Data Grid

```
 public Admin()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var Users = Connect.db.Person.ToList();
        dataGridUsersBank.ItemsSource = Users;

    }
```

А вот кнопка удаление которую я смог на сочинять... но она не работает

```
 private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (dataGridUsersBank.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int idSelectedPerson = (dataGridUsersBank.SelectedItem as Person).PersonId;
            Application.Current.Resources["selectedPerson"] = idSelectedPerson;
            
            Connect.db.Person.Remove.();
            Connect.db.SaveChanges();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Для удаления выберите пользователя");

        }

    }
```

Я пытался передавать разные значения но у меня нечего не вышло

Answer (score 0):

Уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос

```
 if (dataGridUsersBank.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            int idSelectedPerson = (dataGridUsersBank.SelectedItem as Person).PersonId;
            Person person = (from r in Connect.db.Person where r.PersonId == idSelectedPerson select r).SingleOrDefault();
            Connect.db.Person.Remove(person);
            Connect.db.SaveChanges();
            dataGridUsersBank.ItemsSource = Connect.db.Person.ToList();
            MessageBox.Show("Пользователь удален");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Для изменения выберите пользователя");

        }
```

Comment: Советую вам научиться делать привязки, самая вот элементарная: 1. Окну: `DataContext = this;`, 2. В классе окна: `public Person SelectedPerson {get;set;}`, 3. В XAML: `<DataGrid SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPerson}"/>`. Как видите, нет ничего сложного, всего несколько строк, которые избавят вас от этих лишних конвертаций, ибо будете сразу получать нужный объект, WPF позаботится об этом. Касательно вашего кода, зачем вы получаете `Person` из `DataGrid`, из которого вытягиваете ID, пот которому лезете в базу, ищете того-же самого `Person` и его удаляете?